# DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable() to DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

Why does this code work..

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = sitesformdataset.Tables[MainTableStringName].DefaultView.ToTable();
```

When this code does not...

```
sitesformdataset.Tables[MainTableStringName] = sitesformdataset.Tables[MainTableStringName].DefaultView.ToTable();
```

It says "Property or indexer 'System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[string]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Comment: Is this a theoretical question? Because you're trying to add the same table again.

Answer (score 2):

The error is self-explanatory. Because you try to assign a table to the [`Tables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58st33fb.aspx) indexer of the `DataSet` which is readonly.

```
public DataTable this[
    string name
] { get; }  // <-- readonly
```

Comment: Oh sorry I should have added, How do I get it to work without creating a seperate DataTable like in the first segment of code?

Comment: So you have a table and you want to add it to the DataSet? Your example is odd since you want to add the same table again.